# Why is a continuous function of a Riemann-Stieltjes Integrable function, also Riemann-Stieltjes Integrable?

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$, $m\leq f\leq M$, $\phi$ is continuous on $[m,M]$, and $h(x)=\phi(f(x))$ on $[a,b]$. Then prove that $h(x)\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi$ is continuous on $[m,M]$ and this set is compact, $\phi$ is uniformly continuous on $[m,M]$ (Theorem 4.19 of Rudin's PoMA). Therefore (let $s,t\in [m,M]$),

$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta >0; |s-t|<\delta\Rightarrow |\phi(s)-\phi(t)|<\varepsilon. \ \ \ \ \ \text{(I)}$

We can presume $\delta < \varepsilon$. We know that $f\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$, so for $\varepsilon=\delta^2$, exists a partition $\mathscr{P}=\{ x_0,\ldots, x_n\}$ on $[a,b]$ such that

$U(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)-L(\mathscr{P},f,\alpha)<\delta^2 \ \ \ \ \ \text{(II)}$

Presume the following.

$M_i=\sup_\mathscr{P}{f(x)}, \ \ (x_{i-1}\leq x\leq x_i)$
$m_i=\inf_\mathscr{P}{f(x)}, \ \ (x_{i-1}\leq x\leq x_i)$

$M_i^*=\sup_\mathscr{P}{h(x)}, \ \ (x_{i-1}\leq x\leq x_i)$
$m_i^*=\inf_\mathscr{P}{h(x)}, \ \ (x_{i-1}\leq x\leq x_i)$

$A=\{ i |\ \ 1\leq i\leq n, M_i-m_i<\delta\}$
$B=\{ i |\ \ 1\leq i \leq n, M_i-m_i\geq \delta\}$

Then obviously,
$i\in A\Longrightarrow M_i^* - m_i^* <\varepsilon$
$i\in B\Longrightarrow M_i^* - m_i^* <2M^*$, where $M^* = sup_{a\leq x\leq b}{|h(x)|} \ \ \ \text{(III)}$.

Thus,
$\delta\sum_{i\in B}\Delta\alpha_i \stackrel{\text{(III)}}{\leq}\sum_{i\in B}(M_i-m_i)\Delta \alpha_i\stackrel{\text{(II)}}{\leq}\delta^2\Longrightarrow \sum_{i\in B} \Delta \alpha_i\leq\delta\ \ \ \text{(IV)}.$

So,
$U(\mathscr{P},h,\alpha)-L(\mathscr{P},h,\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^n(M_i^* - m_i^*)\Delta\alpha_i$
$\ \ \ =\sum_{i\in A} (M_i^*-m_i^*)\Delta\alpha_i + \sum_{i\in B} (M_i^*-m_i^*)\Delta\alpha_i$
$\ \ \ \leq \varepsilon \sum_{i\in A} \Delta \alpha_i + 2M^* \sum_{i\in B} \Delta \alpha_i$
$\ \ \ \stackrel{\text{(IV)}}{\leq} \varepsilon (\alpha(b) - \alpha(a)) + 2M^* \delta$
$\ \ \ \leq \varepsilon(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))+2M^* \varepsilon := \varepsilon_1$

From a theorem (6.6) in Rudin's PoMA, we finally have
$$h\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$$

$\square$